# Bring Uni event back to the caller thread

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, mutiny

Given a subscription in a Quarkus application:

```kotlin
Uni.createFrom.Item(1)
    .chain { it -> processA(it) }
    .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
    .chain { it -> processB(it) }
    .chain { it -> processC(it) }
    .subscribe().with{ it -> processD(it) }
```

If I understand correctly, `processA` will be executed on the caller thread (so if it is in a Verticle, it should be on a IO thread), `processB` and `processC` will be executed on the worker threads, `processD` will be on the caller/IO thread again.

How can I make `processC` being called on the IO thread, while `processB` still on the worker thread? Is there a simple method to bring the event back to the caller thread?

---

Edit: Right now I am using the following workaround:

```kotlin
Uni.createFrom.Item(1)
    .chain { it -> processA(it) }
    .chain { i -> Uni.createFrom().future { Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool().submit{ processB(i) } } }
    .chain { it -> processC(it) }
    .subscribe().with{ it -> processD(it) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to capture the Vert.x Context and switch back to it.
Something like this would work (using Java, as my Kotlin is not great):

```java
Context context = Vertx.currentContext();
Uni.createFrom().item(1)
   .chain(it -> processA(it))
   .emitOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
   .chain(it -> processB(it))
   .emitOn(runnable -> context.runOnContext(ignored -> runnable.run())
   .chain(it -> process(it))
   .subscribe().with(it -> processD(it));
```

Comment: Most elegant and working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can we get the same result when doing the same on Quarkus? Currently `Vertx.currentContext()` returns null (Quarkus 2.12.2)

Comment: If Vertx.currentContext() returns null it's because you are not on an event loop, but on a worker thread. So, there is no way to switch back to the event loop as you are not on one.